# Rails 3 - Ideal way to set title of pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Whats the proper way to set the page title in rails 3. Currently I'm doing the following:

app/views/layouts/application.html:

```
<head>
  <title><%= render_title %></title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

app/helpers/application_helper.rb:

```
def render_title
  return @title if defined?(@title)
  "Generic Page Title"
end
```

app/controllers/some_controller.rb:

```
def show
  @title = "some custom page title"
end
```

Is there another/better way of doing the above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the title of a page in rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185965/how-do-i-change-the-title-of-a-page-in-rails)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

you could a simple helper:

```
def title(page_title)
  content_for :title, page_title.to_s
end
```

use it in your layout:

```
<title><%= yield(:title) %></title>
```

then call it from your templates:

```
<% title "Your custom title" %>
```

Comment: Very elegant ;) But probably needs to change helper: `content_for :title, page_title.to_s`

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect Andrew's suggestion (Andrea's solution would not work in rails 3)

Comment: The problem is this answer is wrong. Unless there's a magician in here. For title to be set using this helper method `title` must be called before <title><%= yield(:title) %></title>, and since the latter is mostly in layout, this will not work. People have problem understanding this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770419/unable-to-create-a-helper-in-rails

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel What you are saying is not true.  Rails traditionally renders templates first, then the layout.  This changes a bit with the introduction of streaming, but even when streaming is enabled, this would still *work*, though using the new `provide` over `content_for` would be better.

Comment: I've found that (with a little modification) this is also a good way to set `ref="prev"`, `"next"`, and `"canonical"` header tags.

Comment: I guess this is still true for Rails 4, right? If yes, would be nice to note this somewhere in the answer so that people do not wonder whether or not they should continue searching if their Rails version is 4+

Comment: I think sanitize method will be better in case of you need apostrophes in title. Otherwise it will encode as html chars.  `<title><%= sanitize yield(:title) %></title>`

Answer (score 52):

There's no need to create any extra function/helper. You should have a look to [the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield).

In the application layout

```
<% if content_for?(:title) %>
  <%= content_for(:title) %>
<% else %>
  <title>Default title</title>
<% end %>
```

In the specific layout

```
<% content_for :title do %>
  <title>Custom title</title>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 41):

I found that apeacox's solution didn't work for me (in Rails 3.0.3).

Instead I did...

In `application_helper.rb`:

```
def title(page_title, options={})
  content_for(:title, page_title.to_s)
  return content_tag(:h1, page_title, options)
end
```

In the layout:

```
<title><%= content_for(:title) %></title>
```

In the view:

```
<% title "Page Title Only" %>
```

OR:

```
<%= title "Page Title and Heading Too" %>
```

---

Note, this also allows us to check for the presence of a title and set a default title in cases where the view hasn't specified one.

In the layout we can do something like:

```
<title><%= content_for?(:title) ? content_for(:title) : 'This is a default title' %></title>
```

Comment: `content_for?(:title) || 'This is a default title'` is shorter.

Comment: I think what you want in the layout is: <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : 'This is a default title' %></title>

Comment: @mjnissim That would return "true" if there is set a value for title.

Answer (score 3):

This is my preferred way of doing it:

**application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def title(*parts)
    content_for(:title) { (parts << t(:site_name)).join(' - ') } unless parts.empty?
  end
end
```

**views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<title>
  <%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : t(:site_name) %>
</title>
```

**config/locales/en.yml**

```
en:
  site_name: "My Website"
```

This has the nice advantage to always falling back to the site name in your locales, which can be translated on a per-language basis.

Then, on every other page (eg. on the About page) you can simply put:

**views/home/about.html.erb**

```
<% title 'About' %>
```

The resulting title for that page will be:

**About - My Website**

Simples :)

Answer (score 2):

@akfalcon - I use a similar strategy, but without the helper.. I just set the default @title in the application controller and then use, <%=@title%> in my layout.  If I want to override the title, I set it again in the controller action as you do.  No magic involved, but it works just fine.  I do the same for the meta description & keywords.

I am actually thinking about moving it to the database so an admin could change the titles,etc without having to update the Rails code.  You could create a PageTitle model with content, action, and controller.  Then create a helper that finds the PageTitle for the controller/action that you are currently rendering (using controller_name and action_name variables).  If no match is found, then return the default.

@apeacox - is there a benefit of setting the title in the template?  I would think it would be better to place it in the controller as the title relates directly to the action being called.

Comment: It's not a good practice to set a title inside a controller because the former is about View and the latter is about business logic. For example, having a 'blog' controller, it's normal to set a title according to the post.title and there's no reason to make this in controller, but you make it in template or layout file

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def title(*page_title)
    if Array(page_title).size.zero?
      content_for?(:title) ? content_for(:title) : t(:site_name)
    else
      content_for :title, (Array(page_title) << t(:site_name)).join(' - ')
    end
  end
end
```

If `title` is called without arguments, it returns the current value of title or the default which in this example will be "Example".

It `title` is called with arguments, it sets it to the passed value.

```
# layouts/application.html.erb
<title><%= title %></title>

# views/index.html.erb
<% title("Home") %>

# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  site_name: "Example"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/294-playing-with-pjax?view=asciicast). I think it will be very useful and give you basic start.

NOTE: In case you want more dynamic pages with pjax

Answer (score 0):

I have a somewhat more complicated solution. I want to manage all of my titles in my locale files. I also want to include meaningful titles for show and edit pages such that the name of the resource is included in the page title. Finally, I want to include the application name in every page title e.g. `Editing user Gustav - MyApp`.

To accomplish this I create a helper in `application_helper.rb` which does most of the heavy lifting. This tries to get a name for the given action from the locale file, a name for the assigned resource if there is one and combines these with the app name.

```
# Attempt to build the best possible page title.
# If there is an action specific key, use that (e.g. users.index).
# If there is a name for the object, use that (in show and edit views).
# Worst case, just use the app name
def page_title
  app_name = t :app_name
  action = t("titles.#{controller_name}.#{action_name}", default: '')
  action += " #{object_name}" if object_name.present?
  action += " - " if action.present?
  "#{action} #{app_name}"
end

# attempt to get a usable name from the assigned resource
# will only work on pages with singular resources (show, edit etc)
def object_name
  assigns[controller_name.singularize].name rescue nil
end
```

You will need to add action specific texts in your locale files in the following form:

```
# en.yml 
titles:
  users:
    index: 'Users'
    edit: 'Editing'
```

And if you want to use meaningful resource names in your singular views you may need to add a couple of proxy methods, e.g.

```
# User.rb
def name
  username
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought it will be good:

```
<title>
    <% if @title %>
      <%= @title %>
    <% else %>
      Your title
    <% end %>
</title>
```

And give a value to @title in your controller, or the title will be `Your title`

Comment: Simplified: <title><%= @title or 'Title' %></title>

Answer (score 0):

My answer is more simple:

**locales/any_archive.yml**:

```
pt-BR:
  delivery_contents:
    title: 'Conteúdos de Entregas'

  groups:
    title: 'Grupos'
```

And inside of **application.html.slim**:

```
title
  = "App Name: #{t("#{controller_name.underscore}.title")}"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way to manipulate layout variables (title, description, etc.):

```
# app/views/application.html.erb
<title>
  <%= content_for :title || 'App default title' %>
</title>

# app/views/posts/index.html.erb
<%= content_for :title, 'List of posts' %>
```

And other pages will have `App default title` value for their titles

Answer (score 0):

In application layout:

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

<title><%= (yield :title) || 'General title' %></title>
```

then in each view where you want a specific title:

```
<% content_for :title, 'Specific title' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already some good answers, but I'll add my simple approach. Add this to layouts/application.html

```
- if content_for?(:title)
  -title = "My site | #{content_for(:title)}"
-else
  -title = "My site | #{controller_name.titleize}"
```

You automagically get a nice names on all your views like "My site | Posts" -- or whatever the controller happens to be.

Of course, you can *optionally* set a title on a view by adding:

```
- content_for(:title, 'About')
```

and get a title like "My site | About".