# current tab in navigation bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a navigation bar which is an unordered list with tabs as list elements. I'm drawing each individual tab (list item) using a view helper. I want to apply the `active` class on each one based on a value provided by a view. Is this possible?

To elaborate, on the view helper I might have something like:

```
def tab_item(tab)
  content_tag :li, :class => ('active' if some_variable == tab) do
    link_to tab, "/#{tab}"
  end
end
```

And in a specific view I would do:

```
<% somehow_set_some_variable('dash') %>
```

This would then make it so that `some_variable` in the view helper is `'dash'`, making it so that that tab gains the `'active'` class.

Is this possible in any way? If not, is there another approach to this problem? Should I just set a variable on the controller?

I have seen articles and questions already which base the decision based on the current controller and/or action, but this is too restrictive so I am looking to see if I can take this approach. Another solution I came up with is to generate the entire list of tabs in one view helper which takes an argument for the tab to be activated, and I call this in each of the views. However, I'd rather generate the list in the layouts and activate a tab on a per-view basis.

**Workaround**: So far I have come up with a compromise, short of knowing a way of doing what I asked in this question. The application helper creates an `li` tag and applies `activate` if the passed in argument to the application helper matches instance variable `@activate`.

```
def nav_tab(tab)
  content_tag :li, :id => tab, :class => ('active' if tab == @activate) do
    link_to tab, "/#{tab}"
  end
end
```

Then in controller actions I simply set that variable, for example:

```
def index
  # ...
  @activate = 'dash'
end
```

This works, and it has the effect I was looking for: the nav bar is generated independently and then each 'action' can specify which tab to activate, *if* they want.

I am not sure if this is the best solution to this problem. I was trying to keep this stuff within views, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3092076/101090) which accomplishes this for view-specific `<title>` changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this just define a methods in application helper and call it by passing the a unique string  for each navigation list

```
 def active_class(css_class)

    if controller.controller_name == css_class ||  css_class == "#{controller.controller_name}##{controller.action_name}" || css_class == inner_classes
       return "active"
    else
      return ""
    end   
  end


  def inner_classes
    pages = {
      "basic_files#new_part_price_file" => "basic_files#index",
      "basic_files#new_market_basket_file" => "basic_files#index",
      "basic_files#create" => "basic_files#index",
      "basic_files#edit"   => "basic_files#index",
      "basic_files#show"   => "basic_files#index",
      "basic_files#uploads"  => "basic_files#index",
      "basic_files#downloadable_part_price_file" => "basic_files#download_page",
      "basic_files#downloadable_market_basket_file" => "basic_files#download_page",
      "basic_files#download_part_price_file" => "basic_files#download_page",
      "basic_files#download_market_basket_file" => "basic_files#download_page",
    }   
    pages["#{controller.controller_name}##{controller.action_name}"]
  end
```

In the view you could call the above methods like this

```
<%= link_to 'Home',home_path,:class => "f1 #{active_class('home')}" %>

   <% if current_user.publisher? %>
    <%= link_to 'User',users_path,:class => "f1 #{active_class('users')}" %> 
    <%= link_to 'Upload',basic_files_path,:class => "f1 #{active_class('basic_files#index')}" %>
    <%= link_to 'Publish',publish_completed_basic_files_path,:class => "f1 #{active_class('basic_files#publish_completed')}" %>
    <%= link_to 'Report',audits_path ,:class => "f1 #{active_class('audits')}" %>
```

`Note it just a example of how you can build automatic navigation highlighting`