# Undefined method when creating a helper in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-helper

I tried to create a helper module to be able to set the title of a page. Of course it's not working ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059704/rails-3-ideal-way-to-set-title-of-pages))  Is there something I must define in a controller for my helpers methods to be seen by my controllers??

[image: Undefined method]

Gitlink: [works_controller.rb](https://github.com/matthewharwood/blog/blob/master/app/controllers/works_controller.rb)

```
  def index
    set_title("Morning Harwood")
    @works = Work.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @works}
    end
  end
```

In [application_helper.rb](https://github.com/matthewharwood/blog/blob/master/app/helpers/application_helper.rb):

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def set_title(title = "Default title")
      content_for :title, title
    end  
end
```

In the layout [work.html.erb](https://github.com/matthewharwood/blog/blob/master/app/views/layouts/work.html.erb):

```
 <%= content_for?(:title) ? content_for(:title) : 'This is a default title' %>
```

Comment: You added three totally disconnected pieces of code. What you want to achieve?

Comment: Couldn't you just do `<title><%= @page_title || 'default_title' %><title>`

Answer (score 3):

Helpers in Rails are methods available in views (and controllers if you include them) that allow you to avoid code repetition in views.

An example of a helper from my code is a method that renders html for facebook login button. This button is in reality more than user sees, because it's a hidden form with some additional information, etc. For this reason I wanted to make a helper method out of it, so instead of copying 10 lines of code multiple times I can call a single method. This is more DRY.

Now, back to your example, you want to do two things

- display page `<title>`,
- add `<h1>` header at the top of the page.

I see now where linked answer wasn't clear enough. You indeed need helper, but you also need to call it! So

```
# application_helper.rb
def set_title(title = "Default title")
  content_for :title, title
end

# some_controller.rb
helper :application

def index
  set_title("Morning Harwood")
end
```

And then in layout's views you can use:

```
<title> <%= content_for?(:title) ? content_for(:title) : 'This is a default title' %><</title>
...
<h1><%= content_for?(:title) ? content_for(:title) : 'This is a default title' %></h1>
```

Comment: how would I make this into a helper class?

Comment: But why do you insist on having a helper, do you understand what helpers are for?

Comment: And helpers are not CLASSES, they are MODULES.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of understanding of the rails and its proper nomenclature.  I want to create a title helper because the linked referenced above stated that it was best practice to do so.  I felt that this was a good starting point in understanding helper MODULES. I feel understanding how to create helpers will be beneficial for my next task; which is to, create a helper that allow me to add a current class to a anchor tag from a current route. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705898/best-way-to-add-current-class-to-nav-in-rails-3

Comment: @MatthewHarwood check out my more in-depth explanation.

Comment: Hey michael... I'm sorry thanks for all your help.  I'm getting a undefined method `content_for' ... I placed the content_for(:title, "Morning Harwood") inside my works_controller.rb

Comment: Ah, okay, this is one of stupid limitations of Rails. Rewriting my answer

Comment: Damn yet again,
undefined method `set_title' for #<WorksController:0x007fe1c411d598> Updated code with full blocks.  I feel stupid, is there something in this code that's erroring out your answer?

Comment: Is there anyway the helpers arn't being linked(?)? All my models, controllers, and views were generated from Rails' scaffolding.  I didn't explicit do anything to link(?) the helpers.

Comment: What do you mean by link?

Comment: Like maybe the helpers arn't even active( link like not being seen because they are dependant on another file)?  I don't know... Just throwing out ideas... Been trying to read documentation... I have no idea why I'm getting this no method error

Comment: Stupid me, updating again! You need to add `helper :application` in controller

Comment: I'm in bed now but I'll test it out first thing in the morning? and mark it right. Lol or follow up with more errors thanks so much for your help

Comment: I hate to keep coming back here but yet again no method error is being thrown... I've updated my post with a very thorough visual of my process. Do I have to do something with route to make a helpper work? I know you're just as curious as I am as to why this still isn't working... I promise you, I will know wtf a module is after this.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood there's a similar, working, solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059704/rails-3-ideal-way-to-set-title-of-pages/3092076#3092076